# Tomcat7 not started on CentOS

Tags: java, linux, tomcat, centos7, catalina

I have installed Tomcat7 on CentOS. I have downloaded the tar file and unzipped it. Then from bin folder i have started it and in the command line is it showing Tomcat has started. Then i am trying to get in via localhost:8080
But nothing is showing.

I have also tried by creating setenv.sh file and write the JRE_HOME there.

I am also unable to stop the tomcat. Getting following message

```
[root@localhost bin]# ./shutdown.sh 
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.69
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.69
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.69/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-   1.8.0.262.b10-0.el7_8.x86_64/jre/bin/java
Using CLASSPATH:       /opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.69/bin/bootstrap.jar:/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.69/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.69/bin/catalina.sh: line 448: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.262.b10-0.el7_8.x86_64/jre/bin/java/bin/java: Not a directory
[root@localhost bin]#
```

Here is the log file from catalina_out

```
    [root@localhost apache-tomcat-7.0.69]# cd logs/
    [root@localhost logs]# cat catalina.out 
/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.69/bin/catalina.sh: line 396: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.262.b10-0.el7_8.x86_64/jre/bin/java/bin/java: Not a directory
./catalina.sh: line 396: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.262.b10-0.el7_8.x86_64/jre/bin/java/bin/java: Not a directory
/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.69/bin/catalina.sh: line 396: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.262.b10-0.el7_8.x86_64/jre/bin/java/bin/java: Not a directory
/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.69/bin/catalina.sh: line 396: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.262.b10-0.el7_8.x86_64/jre/bin/java/bin/java: Not a directory
/opt/apache-tomcat-7.0.69/bin/catalina.sh: line 396: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.262.b10-0.el7_8.x86_64/jre/bin/java/bin/java: Not a directory
[root@localhost logs]#
```

I have also checked the port list, no other application is using it now.

I am getting these error messages all the time and stuck on this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `JRE_HOME` must be `/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.262.b10-0.el7_8.x86_64/jre`